# Subset and groupby in R

Tags: r

I would like to subset my dataframe, here is an exemple:

```
groups  names   col3
group1  Sp1 OK  
group1  Sp3 OK
group1  Sp7 OK
group1  Sp3 OK
group2  Sp1 OK
group2  Sp2 OK
group2  Sp3 OK
group3  Sp1 OK
group4  Sp1 OK
group4  Sp2 OK
group4  Sp2 OK
```

and the idea is for each group, to only keep those that contain both `Sp1` and `Sp2` and remove the other

Here I should keep groups `2 and 4`:

```
groups  names   col3
group2  Sp1 OK
group2  Sp2 OK
group2  Sp3 OK
group4  Sp1 OK
group4  Sp2 OK
group4  Sp2 OK
```

I tried something like :

```
df2=df %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  df$names == "Sp1" & df$names == "Sp2"
```

But it does not seem to be the correct way.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `filter` after the `group_by` step and make sure that the group have both 'Sp1" and "Sp2" with either `%in%` and `all`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(groups) %>%
   filter(all(c("Sp1", "Sp2") %in% names))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   groups [2]
#  groups names col3 
#  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
#1 group2 Sp1   OK   
#2 group2 Sp2   OK   
#3 group2 Sp3   OK   
#4 group4 Sp1   OK   
#5 group4 Sp2   OK   
#6 group4 Sp2   OK
```

---

Or using `base R` with `table` and `subset`

```
subset(df, groups %in% names(which(!rowSums(!table(subset(df, 
        names %in% c("Sp1", "Sp2"), select = 1:2))))))
```

---

Note the issue with using `&` is that we are checking whether both 'Sp1' and 'Sp2' are in the same row of 'names' which is unlikely to occur.  Instead, the logic would be whether both of them can be found in 'names' for the particular group

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(groups = c("group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", 
"group2", "group2", "group2", "group3", "group4", "group4", "group4"
), names = c("Sp1", "Sp3", "Sp7", "Sp3", "Sp1", "Sp2", "Sp3", 
"Sp1", "Sp1", "Sp2", "Sp2"), col3 = c("OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", 
"OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", "OK")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```